# I need help uploading a csv file in Jupyter note

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am currently taking a course on Python programming. I am having difficulties uploading a CSV file on Jupyter notebook to run a simple linear regression. Find the error image attached below.

[image]

Comment: File not found. Is that file `1.01. Simple linear regression.csv` in the same directory as your notebook? If not, then add the absolute or relative path to the file instead of just the file name.

Comment: Did you actually *upload* the CSV file? Maybe you should add a description that helps others to reproduce the steps you did.

Comment: @Wolf It appears that the notebook is running localhost, so I'm guessing that OP just needs to specify path or move the csv file into the `/notebook` directory where this ipynb lives.

Comment: @JNevill Yes, of course, but if OP talks about *uploading*, maybe there is a simple built-in option to add files to an existing notebook. (I've to confess that I'm not experienced with Jupyter notebooks)

Comment: @Wolf what's OP stand for?

Comment: @Shayan The abbreviation OP (*original poster*) refers to the questioner, so *Lefika*.

Comment: @Lefika, did you already try renaming your file (and changing the notebook accordingly) to avoid spaces in the name?

Comment: @Wolf  - I haven't tried renaming the file. Will try and see how it goes.